# Limiting the number of calls to a function to prevent spam

Tags: python

For example, I poll for the temperature of the room. When it hits 27 degrees, it will call the alert function. But since I poll every second, it will spam.

How to I limit the number of calls per minute?

```
def alert():
  <send to phone>

while True:
   <poll for temperature>
   if temperature > 27 :
      alert()
   sleep(1)
```

Comment: By using `sleep`, as shown in the code, you are already limiting the number of calls. Another method will be to keep a counter, reset it every time the minute changes, and check the counter before sending the alert.

Comment: You wrote in a comment _I would like to run other functions within the same while loop._ That's important information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply insert a longer wait after you send the alert?

```
while True:
   <poll for temperature>
   if temperature > 27 :
      alert()
      sleep(60)
   sleep(1)
```

Comment: this will only sleep(60) when the alert fires.

Comment: Right -- OP wants to limit the frequency of calls to `alert`.

Comment: I would like to run other functions within the same while loop. Opps forgot to mention.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to look up events and/or multi-threading.